# Breakable tcolorbox and centering environment error

Tags: tcolorbox

I believe I have a compatibility problem with `center` environment and the breakable `tcolorbox` package.

What I'm doing is:

```
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{before=\begin{center}, after=\end{center}, width=0.8\linewidth, colback=blue!20!white, colframe=blue!70!white, boxrule=0.3mm, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm}
```

The document is compiled but with some errors:

> ```
> \begin{center} on input line 53 ended by \end{tcolorbox}. \end{tcolorbox}
> \begin{tcolorbox} on input line 43 ended by \end{center}. \end{tcolorbox}
> Missing } inserted. \end{tcolorbox}
> Too many }'s. \end{tcolorbox}
> ```

Beforehand, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Make a complete example so that other can try it out without having to guess and type the necessary code.

Comment: As a side-effect of avoiding other problems, environments cannot be used by `before` and `after` for breakable boxes. But both answers of Christian Hupfer and Harish Kumar show good alternatives to achieve the centering.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Besides that: Using `\begin{center}...\end{center}` for just one breakable `tcolorbox` isn't too much typing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `etoolbox`. `tcolorbox` has facilities for this.

When you say `width=0.8\linewidth,`, to make the box centered, you have to push it to right by `0.1\linewidth`. This can be done by

```
,enlarge left by=0.1\linewidth,
%% enlarge right by=0.1\linewidth  %% if needed from right
```

So this code (template stolen from Christian Hupfer) works as intended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{brokenbox}[1][]{width=0.8\linewidth, colback=blue!20!white, colframe=blue!70!white, boxrule=0.3mm, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm,breakable,enlarge left by=0.1\linewidth,#1}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{brokenbox}[colback=yellow]
  \blindtext[5]
\end{brokenbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bad boy!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No. Ugly boy! `;-)`

Comment: Hey Harish and @ChristianHupfer, thank you guys... you solved my problem!

Comment: @MateoVasco You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

The breaking mechanism uses individual `tcolorbox` enviroments and I assume that the `verbatim` way of `tcolorbox` provides wrong `\end{tcolorbox}` code for the last box -- the `\end{center}` is lost.

Using `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package this can be circumvented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{brokenbox}[1][]{width=0.8\linewidth, colback=blue!20!white, colframe=blue!70!white, boxrule=0.3mm, toptitle=1.5mm, bottomtitle=1.5mm,breakable,#1}


\usepackage{blindtext}


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{brokenbox}{%
\begin{center}
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{brokenbox}{%
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{brokenbox}[colback=yellow]
  \blindtext[5]
\end{brokenbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the two other answers which already solve the problem, here is third possibility. Instead of restricting the width of the box to `0.8\linewidth` followed by some centering method, the `left skip` and `right skip` values could be set to `0.1\linewidth`. Technically, this changes the bounding box and gives the same effect as the answer by Harish Kumar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{brokenbox}[1][]{
  % width=0.8\linewidth,          <---- removed
  leftright skip=0.1\linewidth,%  <---- added
  colback=blue!20!white,
  colframe=blue!70!white,
  boxrule=0.3mm,
  toptitle=1.5mm,
  bottomtitle=1.5mm,
  breakable,
  #1}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{brokenbox}[colback=yellow]
  \blindtext[5]
\end{brokenbox}

\end{document}
```