# LuaLaTeX: Automate multiple compilation with for ToC, Index, Bibliography, Glossary and others on CI

Tags: luatex, miktex, glossaries, automation, titletoc

To have reproducible and reliable builds of documents on a remote CI system I would like to automate all the command line tools and multiple compilations necessary to produce a complete document. This pipeline should work an any document out of the box regardless of which plugins are actually used in the document.

It is my understanding that there is a way for a LaTeX build to automatically perform all necessary steps but so far I had no success with any approach.

#### Details

My current setup is this:

- Documents are written and compiled on my machine using LuaLaTeX and MiKTeX
- The CI consists of the MiKTeX Docker image ([see here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/docker-miktex)) with all custom fonts and resources installed

Locally I have to perform various actions in sequence to compile a document which I have to know as the author of a document. But the CI should be able to build any document without applying special per document settings and produce errors when the doc cannot be compile correctly or something is missing.

#### Example: Glossary

When I need to build a document where I use the `glossaries` package the local build would look like this

```
lualatex doc.tex
makeglossaries doc
lualatex doc.tex
```

Now the CI does not know if the doc requires this step or not but should still be able to build the document. In the glossaries documentation there is mention of the `automake` param and the `--shell-escape` option for compiling documents which I assumed would allow me to compile everything at once but this does not work on the CI. Similarly I have the same problems with ToC, indices, bibliography etc.

#### Summary

Is there a common way to automate complex compilation for different packages? (Either  built in to LuaLaTeX or some custom general purpose scripts)

Is there a problem with my setup which could prevent all the steps from happening automatically?

I have waded through lots of resources for specific packages or LaTeX in general but was unable to find something that works. Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried using latexmk? Does it fails for your use case?

Comment: [arara](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara) is also highly versatile. But I'd go with [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk), as @TeXnician already mentioned

Comment: I was unaware of the existence of these tools - looking into them right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is applying `latexmk` to the CI and applying additional rules to `latexmk` to help with the `glossaries` package.

The automated build does the following after setting up the build environment and the miktex docker image:

```
mpm --install=latexmk
```

When building the document, the following command is used:

```
latexmk -r "<path-to-rc-file>/.latexmkrc" -lualatex -latexoption="-interaction=nonstopmode"
```

The `.latexmkrc` file is in a Git submodule shared between all of our document repositories where we also have our shared document classes etc.

Here are the contents of `.latexmkrc`

```
# This shows how to use lualatex (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX)
# with latexmk.  
#
#   WARNING: The method shown here is suitable only for ver. 4.51 and
#            later of latexmk, not for earlier versions.
#

$pdf_mode = 4;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;

# This shows how to use the glossaries package
# (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) and the glossaries-extra package
# (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) with latexmk.

add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
$clean_ext .= " acr acn alg glo gls glg";
sub makeglossaries {
   my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
   pushd $path;
   my $return = system "makeglossaries", $base_name;
   popd;
   return $return;
}
```

taken from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles).

The end result ensures a consistent build experience regardless of the document and its content. This approach is also flexible and extensible which may allow using the exact same tool chain from a local docker container when writing.

Answer (score 3):

As others and yourself have mentioned, [`latexmk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) seems the correct tool for this job. To see how it can be implemented, let me highlight the relevant bits from my own LaTeX document/template CI pipeline (on GitLab). This should be a usable example for a "complex compilation for different packages". I will go into the accompanying [`Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and [GitLab CI config](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) as well, in addition to the LaTeX-specific/`latexmk` part, because all parts are tightly coupled.

Everything detailed below can be seen implemented and (hopefully...) working [in this project](https://collaborating.tuhh.de/alex/latex-git-cookbook). I am trying to keep this answer as self-contained as possible. The link to the project will contain the latest state, which will eventually supersede this answer.

---

### LaTeX and Distribution (Debian) packages

In the linked pipeline, there are a couple packages requiring special attention in the setup. It is unlikely you will have the exact same requirements, but I am listing them here for completeness.

1. [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), building on top of `glossaries`, requires [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) to convert and process `*.bib` files for `lualatex` to work with.

   This is reflected in the setup two-fold:

   1. The Docker image needs a Java Runtime Environment for `bib2gls`,
   2. `latexmk` needs to be told about the presence of `bib2gls` files.
2. [`pgfplots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) with its `contour` option of `\addplot3` ([examples](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/feature/gnuplot/)) requires the external [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/) program. Again, this is reflected two-fold:

   1. `lualatex` (or the engine of your choice) requires outside write access for `gnuplot` to write its computation results to files for `pgfplots` to read: `--shell-escape` is needed, of which `latexmk` has to be told.
   2. `gnuplot`, as a distribution package (as opposed to a LaTeX package) has to be present, e.g. `apt-get install gnuplot` on a Debian host.
3. LaTeX cannot natively embed `*.svg` files. Embedding such files requires conversion to PDF (or some other embeddable format) first. This can be achieved using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and its [`*.pdf_tex` routine](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg-inkscape). However, this leaves us with two extra files per SVG file: `*.pdf` and `*.pdf_tex`. On every change in the SVG file, the derived files have to be updated. This leads to potential conflicts, also in the context of version control (`git` etc.): which versions are to be kept?

   The [`svg`](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg) LaTeX package solves these problems by automating the conversion process. The generated `*.pdf` and `*.pdf_tex` files can be treated as temporary/derived files and discarded freely. Only the SVGs remain, as a [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth). As a bonus, being [text-based (XML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), they are also suitable for VCS like `git` (which binary PDFs are not really).

   As before, this is reflected in the below setup in two places:

   1. For calling the CLI `inkscape` (as opposed to the GUI; for this to work, `inkscape` has to be on your `$PATH`) for reading and writing, the LaTeX engine requires `--shell-escape`.
   2. `inkscape` needs to be available in the build environment (Docker image).
4. Using [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and its `\newtcolorbox` command, I created a new environment for *Examples*:

   ```tex
   \newtcolorbox[%
     auto counter,%
     number within=chapter,%
     % Set cleveref, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126023/120853:
     crefname={Example}{Examples},
     % List of Examples. *.loe file ending could clash with package thmtools,
     % careful if that is used!
     list inside=loe,
   ]{example}% Name of environment itself
       [2]% Number of arguments for the environment
       []% Default of optional argument, which is the first one. Use it for label
       {%
           beforeafter skip=18pt plus 4pt minus 4pt,%
           width=0.95\linewidth,%
           % Center box; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273111/120853:
           enlarge left by=0.025\linewidth,
           title=Example\ \thetcbcounter: #2,%
           fonttitle=\sffamily,%
           leftrule=1mm,%
           arc is angular,%
           parbox,% Allows regular paragraph breaks
           breakable,% Breaks across pages
           enhanced,% Hands drawing to tikz
           rightrule=0mm,%
           bottomrule=0mm,%
           % Setting what ends up in 'list of' so that '<Title>' is not shown:
           list text=#2,
           #1,%
           colback=black!05,%
           colframe=black!70,%
           % float,
       }%
   ```

   This looks like:

   [image: tcolorbox example box]

   This is relevant because it integrates with [`komascript`](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) using the `list inside=loe` instruction, allowing us to fetch and print a *List of Examples*, like the standard *List of Figures*:

   ```tex
   % Declare a new list of contents, with the file suffix in brackets.
   % This will give access to \listof<name>s
   \DeclareNewTOC[%
       type=example,% This also creates types=example+s, that is by appending an s
       % Listname is "List of <Type>s" by default
       % listname={...},
   ]{loe}
   ```

   Finally, `latexmk` needs to be told about this newly created `*.loe` file. This is important because `latexmk` works by examining auxiliary files for changes to gauge compilation progress and finish.
5. In a similar vein as the previous point, using the [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package will allow us to print a *List of listings* from the generated `*.lol` file. As before, `latexmk` will want to know about it.

Finally, this culminates in the following `.latexmkrc` file:

```perl
# Contents of .latexmkrc

# PERL latexmk config file

# PDF-generating modes are:
# 1: pdflatex, as specified by $pdflatex variable (still largely in use)
# 2: postscript conversion, as specified by the $ps2pdf variable (useless)
# 3: dvi conversion, as specified by the $dvipdf variable (useless)
# 4: lualatex, as specified by the $lualatex variable (best)
# 5: xelatex, as specified by the $xelatex variable (second best)
$pdf_mode = 4;

# --shell-escape option (execution of code outside of latex) is required for the
#'svg' package.
# It converts raw SVG files to the PDF+PDF_TEX combo using InkScape.
$lualatex = "lualatex --shell-escape";

# option 2 is same as 1 (run biber when necessary), but also deletes the
# regeneratable bbl-file in a clenaup (`latexmk -c`). Do not use if original
# bib file is not available!
$bibtex_use = 2;  # default: 1

# Let latexmk know about generated files, so they can be used to detect if a
# rerun is required, or be deleted in a cleanup.
# loe: List of Examples (KOMAScript)
# lol: List of Listings (listings package)
push @generated_exts, 'loe', 'lol';

# Also delete the *.glstex files from package glossaries-extra. Problem is,
# that that package generates files of the form "basename-digit.glstex" if
# multiple glossaries are present. Latexmk looks for "basename.glstex" and so
# does not find those. For that purpose, use wildcard.
# Also delete files generated by gnuplot/pgfplots contour plots
# (.dat, .script, .table),
# and XML file generated by biber runs.
$clean_ext = "%R-*.glstex %R_contourtmp*.* %R.run.xml";

# Grabbed from latexmk CTAN distribution:
# Implementing glossary with bib2gls and glossaries-extra, with the
# log file (.glg) analyzed to get dependence on a .bib file.
# !!! ONLY WORKS WITH VERSION 4.54 or higher of latexmk

# Push new file endings into list holding those files
# that are kept and later used again (like idx, bbl, ...):
push @generated_exts, 'glstex', 'glg';

# Add custom dependency.
# latexmk checks whether a file with ending as given in the 2nd
# argument exists ('toextension'). If yes, check if file with
# ending as in first argument ('fromextension') exists. If yes,
# run subroutine as given in fourth argument.
# Third argument is whether file MUST exist. If 0, no action taken.
add_cus_dep('aux', 'glstex', 0, 'run_bib2gls');

# PERL subroutine. $_[0] is the argument (filename in this case).
# File from author from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401979/120853
sub run_bib2gls {
    if ( $silent ) {
    #    my $ret = system "bib2gls --silent --group '$_[0]'"; # Original version
        my $ret = system "bib2gls --silent --group $_[0]"; # Runs in PowerShell
    } else {
    #    my $ret = system "bib2gls --group '$_[0]'"; # Original version
        my $ret = system "bib2gls --group $_[0]"; # Runs in PowerShell
    };

    my ($base, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
    if ($path && -e "$base.glstex") {
        rename "$base.glstex", "$path$base.glstex";
    }

    # Analyze log file.
    local *LOG;
    $LOG = "$_[0].glg";
    if (!$ret && -e $LOG) {
        open LOG, "<$LOG";
    while (<LOG>) {
            if (/^Reading (.*\.bib)\s$/) {
        rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $1 );
        }
    }
    close LOG;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

`latexmk` will pick this file up and draw configurations from it automatically, *if* it is named `.latexmkrc`. So the need to specify that file's location explicitly vanishes if it is present in `pwd`.

### Build Environment (Docker image)

The required Docker image is most easily obtained using a `debian` base image and installing `texlive-full` (and any required packages mentioned above, or whatever you need). This can be as simple as the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:testing

RUN apt-get update --yes \
    && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
        texlive-full
```

For my own needs, I prepared [a much more involved Dockerfile](https://github.com/alexpovel/latex-extras-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) (comments removed due to character limit):

```
ARG BASE_OS
ARG OS_VERSION

FROM ${BASE_OS}:${OS_VERSION} as BASE

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
        ca-certificates \
        perl


FROM BASE as PREPARE

ARG TL_VERSION
ARG TL_INSTALL_ARCHIVE="install-tl-unx.tar.gz"
ARG EISVOGEL_ARCHIVE="Eisvogel.tar.gz"
ARG INSTALL_TL_DIR="install-tl"

COPY texlive.sh .

RUN \
    ./texlive.sh get ${TL_VERSION} && \
    wget https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/releases/latest/download/${EISVOGEL_ARCHIVE}

RUN \
    mkdir ${INSTALL_TL_DIR} && \
    tar --extract --file=${TL_INSTALL_ARCHIVE} --directory=${INSTALL_TL_DIR} --strip-components 1 && \
    \
    tar --extract --file=${EISVOGEL_ARCHIVE}


FROM BASE as MAIN

ARG BUILD_DATE="n/a"
ARG VCS_REF="n/a"

ARG TL_VERSION
ARG TL_PROFILE="texlive.profile"

LABEL \
    maintainer="Alex Povel <alex.povel@tuhh.de>" \
    org.label-schema.build-date=${BUILD_DATE} \
    org.label-schema.description="TeXLive with most packages, JavaRE, Inkscape, pandoc and more" \
    org.label-schema.url="https://collaborating.tuhh.de/alex/latex-git-cookbook" \
    org.label-schema.vcs-url="https://github.com/alexpovel/latex-extras-docker" \
    org.label-schema.vcs-ref=${VCS_REF} \
    org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0"

ARG INSTALL_DIR="/install/"
WORKDIR ${INSTALL_DIR}

COPY ${TL_PROFILE} .
COPY --from=PREPARE /install-tl/ /texlive.sh ./

COPY --from=PREPARE /eisvogel.tex /usr/share/pandoc/data/templates/eisvogel.latex

ARG TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local/texlive"
ARG TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR="${TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${TL_VERSION}"
ARG TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFCONFIG="~/.texlive${TL_VERSION}/texmf-config"
ARG TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFVAR="~/.texlive${TL_VERSION}/texmf-var"
ARG TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFHOME="~/texmf"
ARG TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFLOCAL="${TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/texmf-local"
ARG TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFSYSCONFIG="${TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR}/texmf-config"
ARG TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFSYSVAR="${TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR}/texmf-var"

RUN ./texlive.sh install ${TL_VERSION}

RUN luaotfload-tool --update || echo "luaotfload-tool not found, skipping."

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    default-jre-headless \
    inkscape \
    gnuplot-nox \
    ghostscript

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    librsvg2-bin \
    pandoc

WORKDIR /tex/

RUN rm --recursive ${INSTALL_DIR}

CMD [ "--lualatex" ]

ENTRYPOINT [ "latexmk" ]
```

It allows the user to specify which TeXLive (drawing from their archives) and Debian versions to build. For this, it requires the following `texlive.sh` script. It picks between the `latest` (Docker) tag and some historic version (e.g. Debian 9, TeXLive 2018), in which case it downloads from the [TUG archives](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Script to fetch `install-tl` script from different sources, depending on argument
# given.

# Error out of any of the variables used here are unbound, e.g. no CLI arg given.
set -u

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 get|install latest|version (YYYY)"
}

if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then
    echoerr "Unsuitable number of arguments given."
    usage
    # From /usr/include/sysexits.h
    exit 64
fi

# From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2990533/11477374
echoerr() { echo "$@" 1>&2; }

# Bind CLI arguments to explicit names:
ACTION=${1}
VERSION=${2}

# Download the `install-tl` script from the `tlnet-final` subdirectory, NOT
# from the parent directory. The latter contains an outdated, non-final `install-tl`
# script, causing this exact problem:
# https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-June/040376.html
HISTORIC_URL="ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/${VERSION}/tlnet-final"
REGULAR_URL="http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet"

case ${ACTION} in
    "get")
        if [[ ${VERSION} == "latest" ]]
        then
            # Get from default, current repository
            wget ${REGULAR_URL}/${TL_INSTALL_ARCHIVE}
        else
            # Get from historic repository
            wget ${HISTORIC_URL}/${TL_INSTALL_ARCHIVE}
        fi
    ;;
    "install")
        if [[ ${VERSION} == "latest" ]]
        then
            # Install using default, current repository
            perl install-tl \
                --profile=${TL_PROFILE}
        else
            # Install using historic repository (`install-tl` script and repository
            # versions need to match)
            perl install-tl \
                --profile=${TL_PROFILE} \
                --repository=${HISTORIC_URL}
        fi

        # For `command` usage, see:
        # https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins.
        # The following test assumes the most basic program, `tex`, is present.
        if command -v tex &> /dev/null
        then
            # If automatic `install-tl` process has already adjusted PATH, we are happy.
            echo "PATH and installation seem OK."
        else
            # Try and make installation available on path manually.
            #
            # The first wildcard expands to the architecture (should be 'x86_64-linux',
            # which might change in TeXLive upstream, so do not hardcode here),
            # the second one expands to all binaries found in that directory.
            # Only link if directory exists, else we end up with a junk symlink.
            EXPECTED_INSTALL_TEXDIR=${TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR}/bin/*

            # `ls` found to be more robust than `[ -d ... ]`.
            if ls ${EXPECTED_INSTALL_TEXDIR} 1>/dev/null 2>&1
            then
                SYMLINK_DESTINATION="/usr/local/bin"

                # "String contains", see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/229606/11477374
                if [[ ! ${PATH} == *${SYMLINK_DESTINATION}* ]]
                then
                    # Should never get here, but make sure.
                    echoerr "Symlink destination ${SYMLINK_DESTINATION} not in PATH (${PATH}), exiting."
                    exit 1
                fi

                echo "Symlinking TeXLive binaries in ${EXPECTED_INSTALL_TEXDIR}"
                echo "to a directory (${SYMLINK_DESTINATION}) found on PATH (${PATH})"

                # Notice the wildcard:
                ln --symbolic --verbose ${EXPECTED_INSTALL_TEXDIR}/* ${SYMLINK_DESTINATION}

                if command -v tex &> /dev/null
                then
                    echo "PATH and installation seem OK."
                else
                    echoerr "Manual symlinking failed and TeXLive did not modify PATH automatically."
                    echoerr "Exiting."
                    exit 1
                fi
            else
                echoerr "Expected TeXLive installation dir not found and TeXLive installation did not modify PATH automatically."
                echoerr "Exiting."
                exit 1
            fi
        fi
    ;;
    *)
        echoerr "Input not understood."
        usage
        # From /usr/include/sysexits.h
        exit 64
esac
```

Further, the TeXLive installation is done manually using their [`install-tl`](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) script. For an unattended install, it requires a [*profile*](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html#PROFILES) file, like this `texlive.profile` (comments removed due to character limit):

```bash
selected_scheme scheme-custom

collection-basic 1
collection-bibtexextra 1
collection-binextra 1
collection-fontsextra 1
collection-fontsrecommended 1
collection-fontutils 1
collection-formatsextra 1
collection-langenglish 1
collection-langeuropean 1
collection-langgerman 1
collection-latex 1
collection-latexextra 1
collection-latexrecommended 1
collection-luatex 1
collection-mathscience 1
collection-pictures 1
collection-plaingeneric 1
collection-publishers 1
collection-xetex 1

collection-context 0
collection-games 0
collection-humanities 0
collection-langarabic 0
collection-langchinese 0
collection-langcjk 0
collection-langcyrillic 0
collection-langczechslovak 0
collection-langfrench 0
collection-langgreek 0
collection-langitalian 0
collection-langjapanese 0
collection-langkorean 0
collection-langother 0
collection-langpolish 0
collection-langportuguese 0
collection-langspanish 0
collection-metapost 0
collection-music 0
collection-pstricks 0
collection-texworks 0
collection-wintools 0

instopt_adjustpath 1
instopt_adjustrepo 0
instopt_letter 0
instopt_portable 0
instopt_write18_restricted 1
tlpdbopt_autobackup 0
tlpdbopt_backupdir tlpkg/backups
tlpdbopt_create_formats 1
tlpdbopt_desktop_integration 0
tlpdbopt_file_assocs 0
tlpdbopt_generate_updmap 0
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 0
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 0
tlpdbopt_post_code 1
```

If you will, this file is the core of the image build process. It specifies which LaTeX packages to download and install. You can modify, and probably most importantly slim down, your build here.
For example, installing/downloading documentation files is explicitly omitted here, something that is not possible when simply running `apt-get install texlive-full`, saving multiple GBs of space.

Note that these images are already built and available (in a continuously integrated way: every `git push` on the source repo will trigger a build) on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexpovel/latex/builds). Using those will net the same image as building it yourself, **without straining the TUG archive servers**. These images are built automatically employing DockerHub's [build hook](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/), where the settings page looks somewhat like (see also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201005132636/https://dev.to/samuelea/automate-your-builds-on-docker-hub-by-writing-a-build-hook-script-13fp)):

[image: DockerHub settings page]

### CI Configuration

This is specific to GitLab.
I have not implemented this for GitHub/Travis yet.

In a given repository with one or more `*.tex` files at the root as well as a `README.md`, the below CI YAML config (without comments due to character limit) will:

1. Pull the image from the above DockerHub repository, replacing any `ENTRYPOINT` instruction with nothing (aka a normal shell). This is important for the `script` part to work, whereas an `ENTRYPOINT` is convenient for running the container on your desktop.
2. Replace the `n.a.` in `\newcommand*{\GitVersion}{n.a.}` and `\newcommand*{\GitShortHash}{n.a.}` from the `*.cls` LaTeX class file (in the project root) with the actual, current values of that build. This allows for the VCS metadata to be printed in the PDF.
3. Build the LaTeX into PDF by simply issuing `latexmk`. It will draw its instructions from `.latexmkrc`, see above.
4. Compile a PDF from the `README.md`, using `pandoc`, which again uses `lualatex` for conversion. This is using a template for prettier output. This step is more of a gimmick/showcase for `pandoc`.

The resulting PDFs are *artifacts* of the CI pipeline and can be downloaded after a successful run.

```yaml
default:
    image:
        name: alexpovel/latex
        entrypoint: [ "" ]
    retry:
        max: 1
        when: runner_system_failure
    artifacts:
        name: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
        paths:
            - "*.pdf"
stages:
    - prepare
    - build

insert_git_metadata:
    stage: prepare
    script:
        - |
            declare -A GITINFO=(
                [GitVersion]=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
                [GitShortHash]=$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
            )
        - |
            for k in "${!GITINFO[@]}"
                do
                    sed -i "s~\(newcommand\*{\\\\$k}\){.*}~\1{${GITINFO[$k]}}~" *.cls
                done
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - "*.cls"
    needs: []

build_latex:
    stage: build
    script:
        - latexmk
    dependencies:
        - insert_git_metadata

build_pandoc:
    stage: build
    script:
        - 'sed -i "s~\(^date: \)\".*\"~\1\"$(date +"%B %-d, %Y")\"~" README.md'
        - |
            pandoc README.md \
            --template eisvogel --pdf-engine=lualatex --number-sections \
            -o README.pdf
    needs: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not know what CI stands for, but if you have GNU make on your machine, you could write a small makefile like this:

```
FILE=yourfilename


.PHONY: clean cleanall

all:$(FILE).pdf

clean:  -rm *.aux *.blg *.out *.bbl *.lot *.lof *.glo *.ist *.acn *.acr *.alg *.glg *.gls *.toc *.bcf *.run.xml

cleanall:  -rm *.aux *.blg *.out *.bbl *.log *.lot *.lof *.glo *.ist *.acn *.acr *.alg *.glg *.gls *.toc *.bcf *.run.xml #report#.pdf



$(FILE).pdf: *.tex
    E:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\lualatex.exe $(FILE)
    E:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\biber.exe $(FILE)
    E:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\makeglossaries.exe $(FILE)
    E:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\lualatex.exe $(FILE)
    E:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\lualatex.exe $(FILE)
```

The example is made for Windows as OS. Instead of E:\miktex-portable...\ adapt the path that fits your installation. If you have GNU/Linux you can set $PATH such that you do not need to specifiy the full path to the executables (i.e. just say 'lualatex $(FILE)' etc.).
It is understood that the reference list is being created using biber and biblatex.  The makefile (same filename) should be placed in the same directory where your *.tex files are located. Then, you just have to enter 'make' in the command line terminal. Likewise 'make clean' and 'make cleanall' can help you to tidy up your directory.

Comment: CI = Continuous Integration -> The .tex files are in Git and every time someone makes changes to the document it gets built and pushed out to public servers as PDF automatically.

Comment: How do you make sure that these are all the build actions that are needed. Is it safe to assume that these are the only additional actions that need to be performed no matter the document at hand?

Comment: Thanks for clarification (CI). Well, for documents that you consider as "complete" (i.e., containing items like ToC, LoT, LoF, glossary, list of references) these are all the actions needed. It would also work with less complex documents. I' m working since many years with that makefile.

Comment: So basically you are saying that this covers all major plugins that would require additional compilation steps and the likelihood of encountering a document which does need extra steps is very slim?